# Aceder aos dados retornados no sucesso de um requisição ajax, dentro de um $('form').on('submit'...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho um $('form').on('submit', function()); e dentro dele gostava de fazer uma chamada de uma funcção que corre um ajax e retorna um array de dados. no entanto ao guardar o retorno da função numa variável a mesma fica "undifined" não é possivel fazer o que quero?

Segue o código exemplo:

Fom submit:

```
$('#form_independentes').on('submit', function(event) {

    let curso_id = 1;
    let ficheiros = getDocuments_(curso_id);
    // variavél ficheiro fica como undefined

});
```

Função getDocuments_ :

```
function getDocuments_(id_curso){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/candidaturas/documents/'+id_curso,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function( _response ){
                    //este console log mostra um array de objetos
                    console.log(_response.documents)
                    return _response.documents;
                },
                error: function( _response ){
                    Materialize.toast('Opps ocorreu um erro. por favor atualize a página e volte a tentar', 4000, 'red');
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```

Segue também um print da consola a mostrar o undefined e o array de objetos
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: na url do `ajax` você está pegando as informações do PHP e passando as informações usando o `json_enconde($array)`?

Answer (score 1):

Isso ocorre porque a função `getDocuments_` não possui `return`. O `return` dentro da propriedade `success` não é capturado pela atribuição da linha `let ficheiros = getDocuments_(curso_id);`.

Sugiro que você incorpore a lógica em uma função que é chamada pela `function` do `success`.

### Exemplo

```
$('#form_independentes').on('submit', function(event) {
    let curso_id = 1;
    getDocuments_(curso_id); //sem atribuicao aqui, pois nao ha retorno
});

function getDocuments_(id_curso){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/candidaturas/documents/'+id_curso,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( _response ){
            //este console log mostra um array de objetos
            console.log(_response.documents)
            setFicheiro(_response.documents) //funcao que realiza as tarefas necessarias com o objeto de resposta
        },
        error: function( _response ){
            Materialize.toast('Opps ocorreu um erro. por favor atualize a página e volte a tentar', 4000, 'red');
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Existe também a possibilidade de retornar o valor para variável `ficheiro` caso você use `async: false` no `ajax`. Porem essa funcionalidade esta sendo [descontinuada](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning) e poderá não funcionar em alguns navegadores. O **Chrome** e o **Firefox**, por exemplo já emitem *warnings* quando isso é feito.

### Exemplo Synchronous

```
$('#form_independentes').on('submit', function(event) {
    let curso_id = 1;
    let ficheiros = getDocuments_(curso_id);
});

function getDocuments_(id_curso){
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/candidaturas/documents/'+id_curso,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false, // ESPERA O RESULTADO ANTES DE CONTINUAR
        dataType: 'json'
    }).responseText;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Requisições ajax são async isto é, elas não bloqueiam o fluxo normal de execução do seu codigo. Portanto enas não retornam absolutamente nada!

Como podes Ultapassar o seu problema??
Para isso sera necessario ajustar o seu codigo da seguinte forma
HTML:

```
$('#form_independentes').on('submit', function(event) {

    let curso_id = 1;
    let ficheiros = false;

    $.ajax({
        url: '/candidaturas/documents/'+curso_id,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( _response ){
        //este console log mostra um array de objetos
        console.log(_response.documents)
        ficheiros = _response.documents;
        // aqui chame a funcao que vai tratar a sua informacao nesse caso a variavel fixeios
        facaAlgoComOsFicheiros(ficheiros);
    },
    error: function( _response ){
        Materialize.toast('Opps ocorreu um erro. por favor atualize a página e volte a tentar', 4000, 'red');
        //return false;
   }
  });
});
```